# gem install pg | error: ‘PQERRORS_SQLSTATE’ undeclared

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, opensuse, pg

I am working in openSuse Leap, using rbenv. After upgrading from Leap 15.1 to 15.2 I have a problem. I cannot make 'gem install pg'.

Reproduce:

```
gem install pg
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib64/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/bin/ruby -I /home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib64/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200827-12823-54e7ke.rb extcon
f.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.
---



find / -name "pg_config" -print
/usr/lib/postgresql10/bin/pg_config


gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/lib/postgresql10/bin/pg_config 
Building native extensions with: '--with-pg-config=/usr/lib/postgresql10/bin/pg_config'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.


    current directory: /home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib64/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/bin/ruby -I /home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib64/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200827-12620-silryo.rb extconf.rb --with-pg-config\=/usr/lib/postgresql10/bin/pg_config
Using config values from /usr/lib/postgresql10/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
checking for PQsetSingleRowMode()... yes
checking for PQconninfo()... yes
checking for PQsslAttribute()... yes
checking for PQresultVerboseErrorMessage()... yes
checking for PQencryptPasswordConn()... yes
checking for PQresultMemorySize()... yes
checking for timegm()... yes
checking for rb_gc_adjust_memory_usage()... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for C99 variable length arrays... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile


current directory: /home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib64/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean


current directory: /home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib64/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling gvl_wrappers.c
compiling pg.c
In file included from /home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from pg.h:20,
                 from pg.c:49:
pg.c: In function ‘Init_pg_ext’:
pg.c:470:64: error: ‘PQERRORS_SQLSTATE’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘PQERRORS_TERSE’?
  rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQERRORS_SQLSTATE", INT2FIX(PQERRORS_SQLSTATE));
                                                                ^
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:261:33: note: in definition of macro ‘RB_INT2FIX’
 #define RB_INT2FIX(i) (((VALUE)(i))<<1 | RUBY_FIXNUM_FLAG)
                                 ^
pg.c:470:56: note: in expansion of macro ‘INT2FIX’
  rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQERRORS_SQLSTATE", INT2FIX(PQERRORS_SQLSTATE));
                                                        ^~~~~~~
pg.c:470:64: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
  rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQERRORS_SQLSTATE", INT2FIX(PQERRORS_SQLSTATE));
                                                                ^
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:261:33: note: in definition of macro ‘RB_INT2FIX’
 #define RB_INT2FIX(i) (((VALUE)(i))<<1 | RUBY_FIXNUM_FLAG)
                                 ^
pg.c:470:56: note: in expansion of macro ‘INT2FIX’
  rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQERRORS_SQLSTATE", INT2FIX(PQERRORS_SQLSTATE));
                                                        ^~~~~~~
pg.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-cast-function-type’
make: *** [Makefile:245: pg.o] Ошибка 1


make failed, exit code 2


Gem files will remain installed in /home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib64/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.2.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib64/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/pg-1.2.3/gem_make.out
```

OpenSuse Support Forum recommended that I report a bug on bugzilla:

*'Looks like although dependencies are satisfied, there is an upstream compilation error likely due to a change in supported methods. Code identified the error, then tried to resolve on its own (apparently there is some error checking and fixes already in the code, maybe errors like this has happened before). That kind of error isn't likely going to be solved by an end user.'*

But this did not solve the problem, please [take a look](https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1175927).
Any ideas? Help would be very helpful.

UPD

```
LC_ALL=C sudo zypper in postgresql postgresql-server postgresql-contrib
[sudo] password for root:
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'postgresql' is already installed.
No update candidate for 'postgresql-12.0.1-lp152.5.5.noarch'. The highest available version is already installed.
'postgresql-server' is already installed.
No update candidate for 'postgresql-server-12.0.1-lp152.5.5.noarch'. The highest available version is already installed.
'postgresql-contrib' is already installed.
No update candidate for 'postgresql-contrib-12.0.1-lp152.5.5.noarch'. The highest available version is already installed.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
```

Comment: You need the Postgres libraries installed. See here: https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:PostgreSQL

Comment: @anothermh, what kind of libraries??

Comment: The Postgres libraries. See the link above, install those packages, retry.

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand.
Are you talking about postgresql-devel? it doesn't solve the problem.
Please name the libraries to install.

Comment: You should report it as an issue in the Ruby pg repository: https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/issues .

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about Leap, but under Tumbleweed I solved exactly the same problem by removing postgresql10-devel and installing both postgresql12-devel and postgresql12-server-devel.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Got exactly the same problem and zypper in postgresql13-server-devel solved it

Comment: I am on Leap and this fixed my problem as well.